# Azure Claim Regex - Unable to filter a claim

Tags: regex, azure-active-directory, saml-2.0, regexp-replace

I am working on running a filter on a Claims called Groups. I am working on an Enterprice Application in the sign-on section.
Once I go into the 2 Attributes & Claims section I select the correct claim and had applied a regex **<GroupName>[A-Za-z-]*-(<Final1>|<Final2>)$** obviously the one in brackets <> are fictitious for the purpose of the regex. The problem is that I am forced to put something Regex replacement pattern. Since I want all groups to be found by the regex how do I not do any replace.
Sorry if this question is probably stupid, but this is the first time I've come up against this.

To make it easier I would like for a user who has 10 roles "found by regex" to pass all others are not displayed.
e.g.

Regex: Pluto[A-Za-z-]*-(Admin|Operator|Pincopallino)$

Groups:

- Pluto-PROD-Admin,
- Pluto-PROD-Operator
- Pluto-PROD-Pincopallino
- Goofy-Admin
- Goofy-Operator

After regex only the Pluto-Admin, Pluto-Operator, Pluto-Pincopallino return to me in the SAML2 response

Comment: Please edit your question to make it more readable. Read the [documentation about the markdown syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion i Edited the question if there is something still to be modified please tell me.

Comment: I still have difficulties to understand what you formally need. Do you also want to match `Goofy-...` groups? if yes, then just change the regex to `^(Pluto|Goofy)[A-Za-z-]*-(Admin|Operator|Pincopallino)$`. Capturing group 1 will be "Pluto" or "Goofy" and capturing group 2 will contain "Admin", "Operator" or "Pincopallino"

Comment: I have user with maybe 300 groups i have to filter only the Goofy ones. the problem is the configuration on Azure. I have 2 text box the "Regex pattern" where i put the Regex to filter the correct groups from the list and "Regex replacement pattern
" where i do not know what to put to see those groups. Both are mandatory. My necessity is to put something in the second text box to allow to see all the group matched in the saml 2

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the software, you may be able to use `&` or `$0` as your replacement pattern to "replace" with the match itself.

Comment: Yes, and sometimes also `\0`

Comment: Thanks of the advice i'll try it, i used something like {0} but i do not know if is correct

Comment: Guys i found the solution is {0}, but i have the problem that i can retreive only 2 groups over more than 2